# How to change the browser of launching asp.net web api in visual studio code?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

When I am trying to run asp.net web api project using visual studio code it lunches on Internet Explorer and I want to lunch it on Chrome .

That is the **launch.json**

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
        // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
        // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net5.0/Catalog.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach"
    }
]
```

}